# CMake: get list of paths to shared libs of a package installed by Conan (to deploy dependencies)

Tags: c++, deployment, cmake, conan

I am looking for a way to deploy dependencies when building project with CMake.

Conan provides a way to deploy binaries of installed dependencies via `[imports]` command in `conanfile.txt`. But this will copy all the dependencies to only one specified path. Besides, this file is not a part of a CMake script.

I want to be able to deploy different dependencies for different targets to their corresponding paths. For example, when I have multilayered CMake project and some targets are being compiled to different locations. I want to do this **within** the CMake script.

The ideal case to deploy shared libraries via cmake is to use targets' properties. For instance, a target can provide `IMPORTED_LOCATION` property, that can be used later by fetching from `$<TARGET_FILE:TARGET>`. Once a full path to the library's binary is provided the binary can be copied to a particular executable's location:

`COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_if_different $<TARGET_FILE:SDL2> $<TARGET_FILE_DIR:MyExe>`

Conan provides a [wrapper](https://github.com/conan-io/cmake-conan) for installation of dependencies which can generate targets of format `CONAN_PKG::PkgName`. However, the definitive list of path to binary libraries is not provided within those targets, so it is not possible to easily acquire the needed list of dependencies to copy via CMake command.

But it does provide a path to binaries and a list of libs for each package. So I am trying to write a function which could generate a list of full paths to binaries from a package name. But I am not successful at this point.

For example, installing SDL2 dependency will generate such contents in `conanbuildinfo.cmake`.
For MinGW in debug:

```
set(CONAN_SDL2_ROOT "C:/Users/Sergey/.conan/data/sdl2/2.0.12/bincrafters/stable/package/39ad275b86c11dca14b78d338f6262dd99e17fbd")
set(CONAN_INCLUDE_DIRS_SDL2 "C:/Users/Sergey/.conan/data/sdl2/2.0.12/bincrafters/stable/package/39ad275b86c11dca14b78d338f6262dd99e17fbd/include"
            "C:/Users/Sergey/.conan/data/sdl2/2.0.12/bincrafters/stable/package/39ad275b86c11dca14b78d338f6262dd99e17fbd/include/SDL2")
set(CONAN_LIB_DIRS_SDL2 "C:/Users/Sergey/.conan/data/sdl2/2.0.12/bincrafters/stable/package/39ad275b86c11dca14b78d338f6262dd99e17fbd/lib")
set(CONAN_BIN_DIRS_SDL2 "C:/Users/Sergey/.conan/data/sdl2/2.0.12/bincrafters/stable/package/39ad275b86c11dca14b78d338f6262dd99e17fbd/bin")
set(CONAN_RES_DIRS_SDL2 )
set(CONAN_SRC_DIRS_SDL2 )
set(CONAN_BUILD_DIRS_SDL2 "C:/Users/Sergey/.conan/data/sdl2/2.0.12/bincrafters/stable/package/39ad275b86c11dca14b78d338f6262dd99e17fbd/")
set(CONAN_FRAMEWORK_DIRS_SDL2 )
set(CONAN_LIBS_SDL2 SDL2maind SDL2d.dll)
set(CONAN_PKG_LIBS_SDL2 SDL2maind SDL2d.dll)
set(CONAN_SYSTEM_LIBS_SDL2 user32 gdi32 winmm imm32 ole32 oleaut32 version uuid advapi32 setupapi shell32 mingw32)
```

for MSVC in Release:

```
set(CONAN_SDL2_ROOT "C:/Users/Sergey/.conan/data/sdl2/2.0.12/bincrafters/stable/package/7ac203a706641e5bebde26147d215ae29c8bc37f")
set(CONAN_INCLUDE_DIRS_SDL2 "C:/Users/Sergey/.conan/data/sdl2/2.0.12/bincrafters/stable/package/7ac203a706641e5bebde26147d215ae29c8bc37f/include"
            "C:/Users/Sergey/.conan/data/sdl2/2.0.12/bincrafters/stable/package/7ac203a706641e5bebde26147d215ae29c8bc37f/include/SDL2")
set(CONAN_LIB_DIRS_SDL2 "C:/Users/Sergey/.conan/data/sdl2/2.0.12/bincrafters/stable/package/7ac203a706641e5bebde26147d215ae29c8bc37f/lib")
set(CONAN_BIN_DIRS_SDL2 "C:/Users/Sergey/.conan/data/sdl2/2.0.12/bincrafters/stable/package/7ac203a706641e5bebde26147d215ae29c8bc37f/bin")
set(CONAN_RES_DIRS_SDL2 )
set(CONAN_SRC_DIRS_SDL2 )
set(CONAN_BUILD_DIRS_SDL2 "C:/Users/Sergey/.conan/data/sdl2/2.0.12/bincrafters/stable/package/7ac203a706641e5bebde26147d215ae29c8bc37f/")
set(CONAN_FRAMEWORK_DIRS_SDL2 )
set(CONAN_LIBS_SDL2 SDL2maind SDL2d)
set(CONAN_PKG_LIBS_SDL2 SDL2maind SDL2d)
set(CONAN_SYSTEM_LIBS_SDL2 user32 gdi32 winmm imm32 ole32 oleaut32 version uuid advapi32 setupapi shell32)
```

Note that names of binaries are different.
My logic is to traverse names from `CONAN_PKG_LIBS_SDL2` and search them in a `CONAN_BIN_DIRS_SDL2`. If there is a file with such a name, it means that it is a binary which needs to be deployed.

Here is my script which does not work:

```
function(conan_get_pkg_libs PKG_NAME OUT_LIBS)
    set(BIN_DIR ${CONAN_BIN_DIRS_${PKG_NAME}})
    foreach(lib_name ${CONAN_PKG_LIBS_${PKG_NAME}})
        find_file(found_lib NAMES ${lib_name} PATHS ${BIN_DIR} NO_DEFAULT_PATH)
        if (${found_lib})
            list(APPEND OUT_LIBS ${found_lib})
        endif()
    endforeach()
endfunction()
```

The scrip either does not find a file, or finds a directory with that name, or finds another file.

Here is my `CMakeLists.txt`

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7 FATAL_ERROR)

project(sdl_conan LANGUAGES CXX)

function(conan_get_pkg_libs PKG_NAME OUT_LIBS)
    set(BIN_DIR ${CONAN_BIN_DIRS_${PKG_NAME}})

    foreach(lib_name ${CONAN_PKG_LIBS_${PKG_NAME}})
        find_file(found_lib NAMES ${lib_name} PATHS ${BIN_DIR} NO_DEFAULT_PATH)
        if (${found_lib})
            list(APPEND OUT_LIBS ${found_lib})
        endif()
    endforeach()
endfunction()

list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/cmake)
include(cmake/conan.cmake)

conan_add_remote(NAME bincrafters
        URL https://api.bintray.com/conan/bincrafters/public-conan)

conan_cmake_run(REQUIRES sdl2/2.0.12@bincrafters/stable
        OPTIONS sdl2:shared=True
        BASIC_SETUP
        CMAKE_TARGETS
        BUILD missing)

conan_get_pkg_libs(SDL2 SDL2_LIBS)

add_executable(app main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(app CONAN_PKG::sdl2)

foreach(lib SDL2_LIBS)
    add_custom_command(TARGET app PRE_LINK
            COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_if_different ${lib} $<TARGET_FILE_DIR:app>
            )
endforeach()
```

---

1. How to make my function work?
2. Is there any way to improve it?
3. Given what I want to achieve are there any better or other approaches?

Comment: Why are you trying to copy the dependencies to build? Why not building directly against dependencies in the Conan cache? That will be straightforward. Typically ``import``ing files into another location is only necessary at runtime, like importing the *.dll files.

Comment: The ``find_file`` will not work in most cases, because the ``libs`` variables contain the library names, like ``sdl``. But the actual files can be something like ``libsdl.a``. You might want to try the ``find_library()`` cmake function instead.

Comment: @drodri `find_library()` won't work with dll files, I've tryied. The actual dll files so far had the same names so far (yes, importing lib file names  `.a` or `.lib` may differ in a way you said). I also don't understand what you were trying to say in the first comment. I need to copy dependent dlls in order to run my executables.